# Sliding an element out as one slides in

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover-over effect where my white box slides to the right and my text slides back into the screen.

You can see from the following video that it works if I hover over the middle of the box but because I am using negative `right` properties, it is glitching out if I hover over it on the left side. Does anyone know an alternative that I can do to get this to work smoothly?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 120px;
}

nav a {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all .4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-box: content-box;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.box,
.navlink {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  height: 35px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.navlink {
  right: -110px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: gold;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.box:hover {
  right: -110px;
}

.box:hover .navlink {
  right: 0;
}

.one {
  top: 0;
}

.two {
  top: 45px;
}

.three {
  top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one">
  <div class="navlink one">Home</div>
</div>
<div class="box two">
  <div class="navlink two">Pizza</div>
</div>
<div class="box three">
  <div class="navlink three">Plaything</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is a background div inside the box with position absolute.

Here is my propos: http://codepen.io/r3npi2/pen/JKNYmd

HTML:

```
<div class="box one">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="navlink one">Home</div>
</div>
<div class="box two">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="navlink two">Pizza</div>
</div>
<div class="box three">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="navlink three">Plaything</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 110px;
  height: 35px;
  right: 0;
}

.box .bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.navlink {
  position: absolute;
  right: -110px;
  font-size:24px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:gold;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  transition: all .4s;
  padding-top:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:hover .bg {
  right:-110px;
}

.box:hover .navlink {
  right: 0;
}

.box.one {
  top: 0;
}

.box.two {
  top: 45px;
}

.box.three {
  top: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best way, depending on your minimal browser requirement, but it will do.

I suggest using 3d transforms to enhance performance, since it triggers gpu.

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.fixed-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
.hover-box {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 35px;
  transition: all .4s;
  position: relative;
}
.hover-box::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 110px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.navlink {
    font-size:24px;
    /* Height hack */
    line-height: 35px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:gold;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(110px,0,0);
}
.hover-box:hover .navlink {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.hover-box:hover:before {
    transform: translate3d(110px,0,0);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-wrap">
    <div class="hover-box one">
        <div class="navlink one">Home</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover-box two">
        <div class="navlink two">Home</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover-box three">
        <div class="navlink three">Home</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xdc6umcd/

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to leave the the box objects as a container with a hover state. But not transition

Have 2 child objects that transition on box:hover

```
.box:hover .slideOff{
left:100%;
}
.box:hover .slideOn{
left:0%;
}
```